# check for existence of a view before creating it

Tags: oracle, postgresql, firebird

I have a table 'X' and I want to drop the table and create a view 'X' only if the view 'X' doesn't exist.
Please let me know how to check this in firebird, oracle, postgres

Comment: Use the `information_schema`, it's standard. Ish.

Comment: oracle : `create or replace view my_view ... ` will do the trick

Comment: @CraigRinger: Firebird and Oracle don't have an `information_schema`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Oracle? Not implementing standards? Why aren't I surprised? Thanks for pointing it out, I didn't know about that limitation.

Comment: @haki PostgreSQL also supports `CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW`, but it won't replace a *table* with a view, and that appears to be what's desired here.

Comment: If you "have a table X" then you can be sure "view X does not exists". You can not have both view and table with the same name (in the same namespace)

Answer (score 1):

In Firebird you can:

```
CREATE OR ALTER VIEW ...
```

or check for existence:

```
SELECT * FROM rdb$relations
WHERE rdb$relation_type = 1
  AND rdb$relation_name = <view_name>
```

Answer (score 0):

A view is just a SQL, you can't drop a table and create a view on it. However, in Oracle, if you want to find whether view X exists in database, just query the view user_objects:

```
select count(*) from user_objects where object_name='X' and object_type='VIEW'
```

If the result >= 0, a view named X has existed. Similar query can be used to query whether a table has existed.

The easiest way in Oracle is just use `create or replace view X as ....`, you do not need to care whether a view named X has exist or not.

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL-specific answer: You can use an [anonymous code block](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-do.html).

First, obviously, if your new view is supposed to give the data from table X, then you can't drop the table.  But assuming the new view X will get its data from somewhere else then:

```
DO LANGUAGE plpgsql $BODY$
BEGIN
    PERFORM FROM information_schema.views WHERE table_name = 'x';
    IF NOT FOUND THEN
        DROP TABLE X CASCADE;
        CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW X AS SELECT * FROM Y;
    END IF;
END $BODY$;
```

Note that although table names are case-insensitive in PostgreSQL, the information schema  `table_name` is CASE-SENSITIVE and values are stored in LOWERCASE (not sure if this is standard or what.)

Also, though not relevant in this case, note that views show up in both the `tables` and `views` tables in the information schema (again, not sure if this is a PostgreSQL peculiarity.)

If the new view IS supposed to have the data from table X, then you can still do it by renaming the table first (this works even if the table X was referenced elsewhere in a foreign key, at least in the trivial case I had -- apparently the view takes over and any underlying object ids are handled auto-magically):

```
DO LANGUAGE plpgsql $BODY$
BEGIN
    PERFORM FROM information_schema.views WHERE table_name = 'x';
    IF NOT FOUND THEN
        ALTER TABLE X RENAME TO _X_table;
        CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW X AS SELECT * FROM _X_table;
    END IF;
END $BODY$;
```